# Create importable class for pipe - Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, pipe, angular5

I'm trying to develop a pipe for replacing specific keywords with proper strings. In order to have a clean structure for this pipe, I'm trying to store my keywords and string in another file and here's the code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AdvEnDictionary } from './advertiser-dict/adv-en-dictionary';
import { AdvFaDictionary } from './advertiser-dict/adv-fa-dictionary';

@Injectable()
export class AdvertiserDictionary {
    constructor(
        private advEnDictionary: AdvEnDictionary['words'], 
        private advFaDictionary: AdvFaDictionary['words']
    ) {}

    getString(keyword:string, lang:string) {
         switch(lang) {
            case 'fa':
                 return this.advFaDictionary[keyword];
            break;
            case 'en':
                 return this.advEnDictionary[keyword];
            break;
            default: 
                 return this.advFaDictionary[keyword];
         }
    }
}
```

And the pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie';
import { AdvertiserDictionary } from '../classes/advertiser-dictionary';
import { PublisherDictionary } from '../classes/publisher-dictionary';

@Pipe({
  name: 'translation'
})
export class TranslationPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private cookieService: CookieService,
    private advertiserDictionary: AdvertiserDictionary, 
    private publisherDictionary: PublisherDictionary, 
  ) {}

  transform(value: string, args?: any): any {
    var [prefix, keyword] = value.split("-");
    var lang = this.cookieService.get("lang");
    switch(prefix.toLowerCase()) {
      case 'pub':
        return this.publisherDictionary.getString(
          keyword.toUpperCase(),
          lang
        );
      break;
      case 'adv':
        return this.advertiserDictionary.getString(
          keyword.toUpperCase(),
          lang
        );
      break;
    }
  }

}
```

And what I keep getting in different scenarios are:

- When simply add the class in the pipe I keep getting 'No provider' error for classes
- When I add the class in module providers I get the 'invalid arguments' for the class and also I don't want to have this class in the whole app I just want it to be used in my pipe.

Comment: What does `AdvEnDictionary` look like? Can you add the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a module that include AdvertiserDictionary and PublisherDictionary

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule], 
  declarations: [
    TranslationPipe  
  ],
  providers: [AdvertiserDictionary,PublisherDictionary], 
  exports:[TranslationPipe]  
})
export class TranslationModule {}
```

but you need import the TranslationModule if you want to use your Pipe

In general

- in imports: all modules you need
- in declarations: components and pipes
- in providers: all the services (all the @Inject)
- in exports: the components that you use outside the module